# Python print 5 words per line from file

Tags: python, file

I am needing to write a code that prints 5 words per line from a text file. I have figured out how to print each line individually on a new line but can't figure out the loop to get it to 5 words per line.

```
def justify(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            for word in line.split():
                print(word)
```

**Example of input:**
This is a test file example. This is just for show. File for testing code.

**Example of output:**

This is a test file

example. This is just for

show. File for testing code.

Comment: Do you have sample input and expected output?

Comment: You could run a counter that increments when you print a word, then `break` from the inner `for` loop when the counter reaches 5, or you can assume there are *at least* 5 words in each line: `print(*line.split()[:5])`

Comment: I read this as saying you want to have every word printed, in a way that puts five words on each line - is this correct? Or do you just want the first five words from each line?

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code, you could add a word counter using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and only print the word if it is in the first 5:

```py
def justify(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            for i, word in enumerate(line.split()):
                if i < 5:
                    print(word, end=' ')
                else:
                    break
            print()
```

Or you could wrap that loop  up as a generator expression and join it with a space:

```
def justify(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            print(' '.join(word for i, word in enumerate(line.split()) if i < 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print all the words in the file, with five on each output line, the following code should work:

```
def justify(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        somewords = []
        for line in file:
            for word in line.split():
                 somewords.append(word)
                 if len(somewords) == 5:
                     print(*somewords)
                     somewords.clear()
        if somewords: # any words left unprinted
            print(*somewords)
```